# Orientability of integrable plane fields

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\xi \subset \text{T}M$ be a integrable plane field on a smooth 3-manifold (i.e. the tangent field of a foliation). Is it true that $\mathcal{F}$ is coorientable?

Comment: Nope.  It's the same argument in dimension $1$, if you replace plane field by line field.

Comment: Can you explain it carefully?

Comment: The tangent bundle of the Klein bottle splits as a direct sum of a trivial bundle and a non-trivial bundle. It's that non-trivial line bundle you're interested in, so your problem is equivalent to finding a non-zero vector field on the Klein bottle -- just take the complementary line bundle once you've found that.  The vectors field comes from a fixed point free action of $S^1$ on the Klein bottle.

Comment: Ok, but if my 3-manifold (or my surface) is orientable? Your example is on a non orientable surface after all.

Comment: Orientability isn't enough in general.   For 2-manifolds it is, but not for 3-manifolds.  For example, $S^1 \times \mathbb R^2$ has an integrable plane field where the foliation consists of a Moebius band and a 1-parameter family of cylinders.  You should think of this as a regular neighbourhood of a Moebius band.